# how to put text at the top of a 3D bar graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d, bar3d

I need to plot a 3D bar graph for my college project ,the bar graph is getting plotted but I want text to be displayed on each bar graph showing the values of its z-axis.

This is code snippet that shows for 2D graph:
[source code link](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# a bar plot with errorbars
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 5
menMeans = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
menStd =   (2, 3, 4, 1, 2)

ind = np.arange(N)  # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, menMeans, width, color='r', yerr=menStd)

womenMeans = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25)
womenStd =   (3, 5, 2, 3, 3)
rects2 = ax.bar(ind+width, womenMeans, width, color='y', yerr=womenStd)

# add some text for labels, title and axes ticks
ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
ax.set_xticks(ind+width)
ax.set_xticklabels( ('G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5') )

ax.legend( (rects1[0], rects2[0]), ('Men', 'Women') )

def autolabel(rects):
    # attach some text labels
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x()+rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height, '%d'%int(height),
                ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)

plt.show()
```

code for 3D bar graph is [source code for 3d bar-graph](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/bars3d_demo.html)

In the 2D version the autolabel function use get_height(), get_x() and get_width() to calculate the height dynamically which in not supported in 3D version it gives:

- patch3d error for function not found

Is there any workaround to display text as in 2D graph.

Comment: look at text3d_demo http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/text3d_demo.html.

Comment: thanks [igavriil](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2294660/igavriil)

Comment: glad you figure it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract the bar coordinates directly from the data and use matplotlib.pyplot.[text](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text), as pointed out by [igavriil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2294660/igavriil). For the example you provided that would look like this:

```
# Note that z and y-axis are swapped in the plot.
for x,y in zip(xs,ys):
    ax.text(x,z,y,'%2.2f'%y, horizontalalignment='left', verticalalignment='bottom')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [igavriil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2294660/igavriil) that link helped and also thanks [hr tur tur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4469367/hr-tur-tur)

I didn't got that parameter `'%2.2f'%y` how it works, there might be more cleaner way to plot this but I ploted it like this:

```
    def autolabel():
    """ attach some text labels"""
    for i in range(0, n):
        ax.text(int(x[i])+1, y[i]-2, z[i]+0.05, str(y[i])[0:4],     color='#660066', backgroundcolor= '#c187e1', weight= 'bold', rotation='vertical', fontsize=10, horizontalalignment='left', verticalalignment='bottom')
```

Link:

[DropBox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2sn9rqrvwnnqi4x/figure_1.png?dl=0)